# Objective-C multiple inheritance issue, I need to inherit my AppDelegate with WTAppDelegate and UIResponder

Tags: multiple-inheritance

I am integrating `WebTrends` into my app.

I need to inherit my `AppDelegate` with `WTAppDelegate` but its already inherited with `UIResponder`.

*How can I inherit my `AppDelegate` with `WTAppDelegate` and `UIResponder`?*

Comment: What is within WTAppDelegate? Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance with classes, only protocols. You might not necessarily need UIResponder but I don't know your situation.

Comment: WTAppDelegate is a class inheriting from NSObject, its for integrating the webTrends into app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that WtAppDelegate should inherite of UIResponder, that in turn inherites from NSObject, and not from NSObject directly.